# LoadError: expected package `Execute [ef016c93]` to be registered

Tags: package, julia

I am trying to use Documenter.jl and have installed the package I want to document ("Execute"), but when I try to run the script, I get the error:

LoadError: expected package `Execute [ef016c93]` to be registered

I installed the package using ] and then typing "dev URL_to_Github" and later entering my username/password.

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: If the code is on GitHub, can you post the link here so I can take a quick look?